# HTC Aria 2.2 ignores EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY intent

Tags: android, video, video-capture

In my application I'm trying to launch the Video with resolution set to minimum.
I'm using the EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY intent for that.
Here is the relevant code:

```
int NEW_VIDEO = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 600000);
startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_VIDEO);
```

However, when the video camera starts it is set to the resolution that was previously defined in the device and ignores the EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY intent.

Does anybody encountered this issue before?

Thanks,
Yair

Answer (score 0):

HTC Desire behaves same way with videos.

It also ignores uri if you want to define where to save the video. Capturing pictures works perfectly. I guess there is some mishap in Sense UI regarding video capture.